# Incorrect syntax near 'First Name'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Records [First Name]='" + textBox2.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + textBox3.Text + "',[Middle Initial]='" + comboBox1.Text + "',Gender='" + comboBox2.Text + "',Address='" + textBox4.Text + "',Status='" + comboBox3.Text + "',Year='" + comboBox4.Text + "',Email='" + textBox5.Text + "',Course='" + comboBox5.Text + "',[Contact Number]='" + textBox6.Text + "'+     WHERE ([Student ID]='" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: It looks like you need the `SET` keyword. Your query is also prone to SQL Injection attacks. Consider using parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the "Set" Keyword:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Records SET [First Name]='" + textBox2.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + textBox3.Text + "',[Middle Initial]='" + comboBox1.Text + "',Gender='" + comboBox2.Text + "',Address='" + textBox4.Text + "',Status='" + comboBox3.Text + "',Year='" + comboBox4.Text + "',Email='" + textBox5.Text + "',Course='" + comboBox5.Text + "',[Contact Number]='" + textBox6.Text + "'+     WHERE ([Student ID]='" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Others have pointed out the missing `SET` keyword in your SQL Command, but so far (surprisingly) no one has pointed out that you're also ripe for SQL Injection.  I would suggest using parameterized queries to neutralize that threat:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Records SET [First Name]=@FirstName, [Last Name]=@LastName,[Middle Initial]=@MiddleInitial,Gender=@Gender,Address=@Address,Status=@Status,Year=@Year,Email=@Email,Course=@Course,[Contact Number]=@ContactNumber WHERE ([Student ID]=@StudentID)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleInitial", comboBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", comboBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", comboBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", comboBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", comobBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", textBox6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", textBox1.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I belive this should be

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Records set [First Name]='" + textBox2.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + textBox3.Text + "',[Middle Initial]='" + comboBox1.Text + "',Gender='" + comboBox2.Text + "',Address='" + textBox4.Text + "',Status='" + comboBox3.Text + "',Year='" + comboBox4.Text + "',Email='" + textBox5.Text + "',Course='" + comboBox5.Text + "',[Contact Number]='" + textBox6.Text + "'+     WHERE ([Student ID]='" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

The difference is the word "Set"

Comment: I just did what you guys have said but it has another error
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: I would try removing the () around the where clause. Though I'm not positive on that one

Comment: In the original query there was also an extra plus sign before the WHERE keyword.

Comment: @randcd Good catch! Johncam take a look at that

Comment: I did it I just forgot the word SET before the [First Name] and remove  the plus sign before the word WHERE. thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for update query is wrong.you might have forgot to add the "SET" keyword..

Update query syntax can be found here:- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Records SET [First Name]='" + textBox2.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + textBox3.Text + "',[Middle Initial]='" + comboBox1.Text + "',Gender='" + comboBox2.Text + "',Address='" + textBox4.Text + "',Status='" + comboBox3.Text + "',Year='" + comboBox4.Text + "',Email='" + textBox5.Text + "',Course='" + comboBox5.Text + "',[Contact Number]='" + textBox6.Text + "'+     WHERE ([Student ID]='" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```